# How to square a complex number with itself

Tags: matlab, math

`a = [1;2;3]`;

`square_real = a'*a`;

ans =

```
14
```

a =

```
 1
 2
 3
```

In this example I am squaring the numbers in variable `a` (an array) with itself.

TO do the same operation i.e., square for a complex number with itself, what is the operation? Should I take ctranpose or conjugate transpose? I am confused.

```
>> ac=[1 + 1j; 2 + 2j; 3 + 0.1j]

ac =

   1.0000 + 1.0000i
   2.0000 + 2.0000i
   3.0000 + 0.1000i

>> ac'*ac

ans =

   19.0100
```

I don't know if I am taking the correct operator.

**UPDATE based on comments received :** I don't want the elements of the complex valued array to change its sign. I want to multiply the array with itself so as to get a scalar answer upon multiplication. In order to do that what should be the symbol in maths and the corresponding command in Matlab?

Comment: Are you looking for the complex conjugate transpose (`'`) or for the transpose (`.'`). They are the same for real numbers, not for imaginary though. (hint: you want the transpose)

Comment: What is your goal, a function that is polynomial in the inputs or the norm of the vector?

Comment: So you want `x.^2` to get the elementwise square?

Comment: @SrishtiM: It sounds like you want an inner product (i.e. dot product), in which case you should use `.'` instead of `'` as Ander suggested. The `.'` operator transposes the array without changing the contents, whereas `'` will flip the signs of the imaginary components.

Comment: What specific scalar value do you want in the example you've given? If you don't know what mathematical result you want then we can't help you with the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments and by you, you need [transpose `.'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) here not [complex conjugate transpose `'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html). For real numbers, transpose and complex conjugate transpose are same since there is no iota `i` or `j` involved. So what you're looking for is this:

```
ac = [1 + 1j; 2 + 2j; 3 + 0.1j];
req = ac.' * ac;
```

If you want its scalar magnitude as output, use [**`abs`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) i.e.

```
abs(req)
```

---

As far as notations in Mathematics are concerned, transpose is usually represented by: 
 
• Aᵀ
 
• A' (it is complex conjugate transpose in MATLAB though)

whereas complex conjugate transpose is usually denoted by:
 
• Aᴴ
 
•  (A̅)<sup>T</sup>
 
• A*

But be careful, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) mentioned:

> In some contexts, `A*` denotes the matrix with complex conjugated
>   entries, and the conjugate transpose is then denoted by `A*ᵀ` or `Aᵀ*`

It is always a good practice to define the notations that you're going to use in your text.

Comment: @SrishtiM As I have mentioned it in the answer. `.'` is transpose, its mathematical symbol will be `Aᵀ` (doesn't matter you have a real number or complex). Some other variants are mentioned in the answer. Regarding when to use `*` and superscript `H`, they are same and both can be used. Regarding your last comment, it doesn't matter whether you have real numbers or complex, the correct mathematical expression for `a.' * a` is `aᵀ a`